# Eslint - configured rules location

Tags: angular, eslint, nrwl-nx, typescript-eslint, nrwl

I am trying to locate where the default eslint rules are for an out of the box configured Nx workspace.

I see some plugins being used in the eslintrc file at the root of my project:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": ["**/*"],
  "plugins": ["@nrwl/nx"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx", "*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "rules": {
        "@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries": [
          "error",
          {
            "enforceBuildableLibDependency": true,
            "allow": [],
            "depConstraints": [
              {
                "sourceTag": "*",
                "onlyDependOnLibsWithTags": ["*"]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@nrwl/nx/typescript"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@nrwl/nx/javascript"],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone tell me where I should be able to see the full list of rules enabled please?

Comment: I am not sure about nx but angular-eslint recommends you use https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/master/packages/integration-tests/fixtures/v1123-multi-project-manual-config/.eslintrc.json and there are rules here that you can change

Comment: Can you show the .eslintrc file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules come from the npm package [@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx). This is the name of the package included in the list of `plugins` without "eslint-plugin-", which is prepended automatically by ESLint when resolving the plugin location.

Following the link to the monorepo https://github.com/nrwl/nx, and digging into the "packages" folder we discover the source of [eslint-plugin-nx](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-nx). Now, looking into [package.json](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-nx/package.json) we see that the `main` module points to `"./src/index.js"`, which is autogenerated by Typescript from [`"./src/index.ts"`](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-nx/src/index.ts). This .ts file imports definitions from modules in the subfolders "config" and "rules" and maps them to exports. So the sources for the locations contained in your .eslinrc file are like this:

- `@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries`: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-nx/src/rules/enforce-module-boundaries.ts
- `@nrwl/nx/javascript`: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-nx/src/configs/javascript.ts
- `@nrwl/nx/typescript`: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-nx/src/configs/typescript.ts

ESLint works by merging the rule definitions in the `extends` sections ([.js](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-nx/src/configs/javascript.ts#L28-L33), [.ts](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-nx/src/configs/typescript.ts#L23-L28)) and then applying the `rules` definitions ([.js](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-nx/src/configs/javascript.ts#L34-L45), [.ts](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-nx/src/configs/typescript.ts#L29-L34)) of the configurations, and finally the rule `@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries` as defined in your .eslintrc file (Note also the `overrides` for [.tsx](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-nx/src/configs/typescript.ts#L38-L40)).

Comment: Fantastic answer - Thank you sir!

Comment: Happy to help :)